# How to group by on a field inside an array of an array of records?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema -

[name: StringType, grades: ArrayType(
StructType(
StructField(subject_grades,
ArrayType(StructType(StructField(subject,StringType,false), StructField(grade,LongType,false)]

I want to `groupby` on the subject field inside the `subject_grades` array which is inside the grades array.

I tried

```
sql.sql("select ... from grades_table group by grades.subject_grades.subject")
```

but I get

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'grades.subject_grades[subject]' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, 'subject' is of string type.;
```

I understand why I get this error, however I was hoping I could avoid exploding the entire thing in order to group by on the inner field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are (relatively) hard to work with and beg for `explode` (or `flatMap`) to work with them when the main query requires the elements inside, e.g. for grouping.

Something I **learnt** from the question is that the following clause with `subject_grades` being of type `ArrayType` is translated to a clause with `subject` being the index and hence the requirement of integral type.

```
group by grades.subject_grades.subject
```

I'd see no other way but using `explode` (or `flatMap`) to "destructure" the `subject_grades` array and do the grouping.